# Как получить данные текстового поля html?

Tags: html, html5

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Find</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:url value="/find" var="var"/>
<form action="${var}" method="POST">
    <label for="type">Type of Specialist</label>
    <input type="text" name="type" id="type">
    <input type="submit" value="Найти">
    <a href="/find/${type.value}">edit</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Извиняюсь за тупой вопрос. Но как обратиться к данным из текстового поля? Есть инпут на форме, пользователь в него вводит данные. Дальше они мне нужны в адресной строке браузера, чтобы потом их извлечь.Нужно что-то типа "value" для текстового поля. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: JS\JQuery наше всё... Если будет нормально оформлено - покажу точнее, набирать ваш пример руками - лень.

Comment: Вы не могли бы вставить код как текст?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" onChange='$("#chk").attr("href","/find/"+$(this).val());'>
<a id='chk' href="/find/">edit</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orL48equ/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Он помог мне разобраться. Еще раз извиняюсь за такой тупой вопрос.